Conditional formatting based on partial text in another cell
I have a google sheet, I want each cell in column B to change colour if the cell on the same row column F includes the phrase "RF FTE". It may also have other data in that cell but if "RF FTE" is included I would like the Cell in B to change colour.
I'm usually good at this but it isn't working for me this time.

please [edit] your question to include the conditional format rule you are using to include text contains and/or upload a sample sheet using sample sheet maker

Custom formula in rule for column B:
=FIND("RF FTE", F1) 

If you want it to be case-insensitive then use
=SEARCH("RF FTE", F1) 

Because it is in a conditional format rule, we don't need to handle the errors if the search fails. On rules conditions are either TRUE or not TRUE, an error is equivalent to FALSE.
FIND  SEARCH

Thank you, That works perfectly. As I said I can usually work it out but this one stumped me lol

@Pete consider editing your older closed question Auto fill in some of the sheet so it can be reopened. You can provide sample data anonymously using Blank Sheet Maker

I see this is your first answered question. Optionally, consider upvoting and/or accepting an answer if it solves your problem. See What can I do when someone answers my question?
